# Chrome Extention Access Blocked (even though user in trusted accounts and in google groups)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a unapproved chrome extention where I want to add another developer to have access, but I contionously get this Access Blocked error. What is the reason behind this ?

Its driving me crazy and I have googled a lot. 2 things I have tried:

- Adding developer to trusted account
- Creating Google Groups and giving access of my extention to this group. In this group, I also added the developer who needs access and gets this error.

[image: 3]

Sign in with Google
Access blocked: Al-EMAIL-358 has not completed the Google verification process

*AI-EMAIL-358 has not completed the Google verification process. The app is currently being tested, and can only be accessed by developer-approved testers. If you think you should have access, contact the developer.
If you are a developer of Al-EMAIL-358, see error details.
Error 403: access_denied*

I have added the developer to trusted accounts but it still does not work
[image]

Comment: Are you a developer?

Comment: yes, its 2 of us working on this. I am also a developer

Comment: @NorioYamamoto did you ever encounter this problem ?

Comment: Do you have access?

Comment: Yes I have complete access, as i am main developer and I created the extention. I just have another team member who i want to give access and its not working for him